# C++ Saving file with unicode name problem - How to save UTF-8 filenames correctly in a crossplatform manner?

Tags: c++, file, boost, unicode, save

I want to save a file with name `Привет Мир.jpg` I receive a string (read it from file for example) (with unicode in it) but my C++ code saves it as `ÐÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ ÐÐ¸Ñ.jpg`
What shall I do to save it correctly? (btw if I just save that string into file it saves correctly, meaning only the way I save filename is some whay wrong. How to fix this?)

Here is my code for file saving:

```
void file_service::save_string_into_file( std::string contents, std::string name )
{
    std::string pathToUsers = this->root_path.string() + "/users/";
    boost::filesystem::path users_path ( this->root_path / "users/" );
    users_directory_path = users_path;
    general_util->create_directory(users_directory_path);
    std::ofstream datFile;
    name = users_directory_path.string() + name;
    datFile.open(name.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::out    );
    datFile.write(contents.c_str(), contents.length());
    datFile.close();
}
```

where

```
void general_utils::create_directory( boost::filesystem::path path )
{
    if (boost::filesystem::exists( path ))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        boost::system::error_code returnedError;
        boost::filesystem::create_directories( path, returnedError );
        if ( returnedError )
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("problem creating directory");
        }
    }
}
```

Update: [with help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975267/c-saving-file-with-unicode-name-problem-how-to-save-utf-8-filenames-correctly/6975299#6975299) I now have

```
void file_service::save_string_into_file( std::string contents, std::string s_name )
{
    boost::filesystem::path users_path ( this->root_path / "users" );
    users_directory_path = users_path;
    general_util->create_directory(users_directory_path);
    boost::filesystem::ofstream datFile;
    boost::filesystem::path name (users_directory_path / s_name);
    datFile.open(name, std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::out    );
    datFile.write(contents.c_str(), contents.length());
    datFile.close();
}
```

But when I save file it saves its file name as `РџСЂРёРІРµС‚ РњРёСЂ.jpg` so.. What shall I do now?

Comment: You are using `std::string`. Are your strings UTF-8 encoded. What OS are you using?

Comment: Currently I use Win 7 but I also need to support Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: You first of all need to deal with the fact that Windows use UTF-16 and *nix uses UTF-8.

Comment: This is not a C/C++ problem. Thisis do do with your OS and its file-system. You need to review how the file-system stores file names.

Comment: Strings do not exist without an encoding. What encoding is `s_name` in? If you don't know, then you've got problems.

Comment: Well.. I thought this should be UTF-8... I get s_name via something like `http_util->parse_multipart_form_data(request->body).find("file_name")->second` where parse_multipart_form_data is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972869/how-to-parse-form-post-request-containing-file-into-mapstring-string).

Comment: and request->body should be UTF-8 encoded string... because it is sent to us from browser... I hope..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard library is not Unicode aware. Therefore, you must use a library (like Boost.Filesystem) that is Unicode aware.

Alternatively, you have to deal with platform-specific issues. Windows supports UTF-16, so if you have UTF-8 strings, you need to convert them to UTF-16 (std::wstring). Then you pass those as filenames to the iostream file opening functions. Visual Studio's version of the file streams can take a `wchar_t*` for the filename.

Comment: So how to save file via  Boost.Filesystem so to have correct filename?

Comment: You use one of the [file streams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#File-streams) that Boost.Filesystem uses. Or you just get the native string from the `path` object (which will be a `std::wstring` on Windows and a `std::string` elsewhere) and feed it to the `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Hm... Is your way any how integratable into my save_string_into_file function?

Comment: You replace `std::ofstream` with `boost::filesystem::ofstream`, from the link I gave you. Then you give it the `boost::path` directly instead of turning it into a `std::string`.