# Create file in arabic name in c++

Tags: c++, g++

I want to create file having arabic name in C++. Below is the program that I tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    const char *path="D:\\user\\c++\\files\\فثسف.txt";
    std::ofstream file(path); //open in constructor
    std::string data("Hello World");
    file << data;

    return 0;
}
```

But file gets created with junk characters: ÙØ«Ø³Ù.txt.
I am using windows platform and g++ compiler.

Comment: Does it help using unicode escapes?

Comment: What is the encoding of the `.cpp` source file? What IDE or editor are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code. Encoding of the file is UTF-8

Comment: Are you able to simply print the name of the file? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c

Comment: Have you tried `const wchar_t *path` instead? Unfortunately, this is a bit of a pain in general. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975267/c-saving-file-with-unicode-name-problem-how-to-save-utf-8-filenames-correctl

Comment: The compiler may or may not support embedding non-ascii in the source file -- try using unicode escape sequences instead (e.g. `\u00ab`). Also you should make the path be wide characters

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding for string literals can be specified with the `-fexec-charset` compiler option for gcc / g++.

In C++11 and later, can also use the `u8`, `u`, and `U` prefixes to strings to specify UTF8, UTF16, and UTF32 encodings:

```
const char * utf8literal = u8"This is an unicode UTF8 string! 剝Ц";
const char16_t * utf16literal = u"This is an unicode UTF16 string! 剝Ц";
const char32_t * utf32literal = U"This is an unicode UTF32 string! 剝Ц";
```

Using the above prefixes can upset some functions who aren't expecting these specific types of strings though; in general it may be better to set the compiler option.

There's a great writeup about this topic on this blog post: http://cppwhispers.blogspot.com/2012/11/unicode-and-your-application-3-of-n.html

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF8:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
  namespace fs = std::filesystem;
  fs::path path { u8"فثسف.txt" };
  std::ofstream file { path };

  file << "Hello World";

  return 0;
}
```

<sup>Using `<filesystem>` library may require additional compiler/linker options. GNU implementation requires linking with -lstdc++fs and LLVM implementation requires linking with -lc++fs</sup>